# Отправка сообщений в discord.py в соседние каналы сервера

Tags: python, бот, discord.py, discord

Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли через бота Discord.py отправлять сообщения в другой канал сервера, если есть ID этого канала. И если можно, то как это сделать?

> Например: участник выполняет команду /com1 [текст] в канале "Channel 1" с ID 0001, и бот отправляет [текст] в канал "Channel 2" с ID 0002.

Comment: `channel = bot.get_channel(0002)`, `await channel.send('текст')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
channel = bot.get_channel(ID нужного канала)
await channel.send(Текст)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять немного более развернутые ответы. Дополнить ответ можно, нажав кнопку [edit].